# How can I run multiple PHP threads through Ruby through PHP? (Yes, PHP->Ruby->PHP)

Tags: php, ruby, multithreading

I have a site heavily developed in PHP, but due to a lack of support for threading, I've decided to use Ruby.

I'd like to know the fastest way to execute a Ruby script and pass some data from PHP, that will in turn execute multiple PHP scripts from Ruby, and pass the results back to the original PHP script.

Comment: You know there's a PECL threading library for PHP right?

Comment: I think you are trying to go at it the wrong way, would you care explaining in your question what you want to actually achieve ? For example, what do you need threading for ? There probably is a better way to do that

Comment: Well I am using a modified version of the PHP SimplePie library to get feeds into PHP, the problem is that when grabbing 40 or so feeds, it can take well over a minute because it is working on a one feed at a time. So my plan was to use a PHP page, which would load Ruby, that would run multiple SimplePie instances at the same time, returning the result

I've looked at PHP threading tricks and none of them are easy or reliable to implement with the way I've written the code, so I was hoping for an easy solution using a different language.

For those curious, the site is http://geeje.com

Comment: I've thought about using Ajax, it would work, but involve alot of programming to get it working with the current app. It looks like I'm going to go the Ajax route anyway, I was just hoping someone may have had a similar issue and found an fast solution. Thanks Jason

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite sure this will never net you any gain over a standard multiprocess model like Apache mod_php, and ruby does not seem like the optimal language to try.  What do you gain by running something in threads?  Basically you share the code, keep it in memory, and then you can hopefully saturate multiple processors by keeping busy during io-wait etc. But it requires certain safety measures (thread-safety).  So the first question is how can you keep a bunch of PHP code in memory to serve multiple processes?  Honestly I don't know enough about PHP internals to know how that would be possible, but I guess Zend Cache is where I would start investigating.